# Some questions about ethereum swarm

Tags: go-ethereum, swarm

I have read https://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/up-and-download.html.
But it does not make sense. So I want to ask a few questions.

1. After syncing geth and swarm, I uploaded the data to swarm.
   The data then exists as a chunk. Are these chunks stored in geth's block? Or where are they stored and provided to the nodes?

2.
Where can I find chunks?

3.
Where is my uploaded data stored on my computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `swarm` only uses `geth` for access to the blockchain. Currently `swarm` only uses the blockchain for [ENS](https://ens.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). That means for the time being you can run `swarm` without `geth` at all if you wish.
2. `swarm` has its own store, implemented as a [leveldb](http://leveldb.org/) database. (see `<datadir>/swarm/bzz-<account>/chunks`). `swarm` storage has nothing to do with `geth` or the blockchain.
3. All (full) nodes in the swarm network participate in the storing of chunks. When you upload something, the chunks will temporarily be stored in your store, but only the chunks that are *your node's responsibility* will be kept there over time. When you request some data from your node, any chunks that are part of that data missing in your node's store will be retrieved from other nodes.

Note that 3. is a rather simplified explanation. Please refer to the [architecture section of the docs](https://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/architecture.html) if you want to go more in depth.

Comment: thx!!!!!!!!!!!! thx!!!!